# sending Zoneddatetime field in json to java restful webservice

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc

I have a rest service which stores the data in database.In my DTO object,I have a DOB field which is of type : 
private **ZonedDateTime** dateOfBirth;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createStudent(@Valid @RequestBody StudentDTO studentDto) {

//I have some more fields in StudentDTO along with dob field.
}
```

I am getting `JsonMappingException(Index cannot be parsed)` When I send request from postman with value : 
`dateOfBirth":"2017-10-01T01:00`

**Question** : How can I convert the datetime format to required format?
If I have to conversion code, where should I write?because when I send the request from postman the data is automatically binded to object using @RequestBody.So,How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Do you have `jackson-datatype-jsr310` in your dependencies? This introduces set of serialisers that allow to work with  java-8 date-time classes.

Comment: I wrote custom deserializer using @JsonDeserialize.Below is the code:
@JsonDeserialize(using = ZonedDateDeserializer.class)
private ZonedDateTime date;

 public class ZonedDateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<ZonedDateTime> {
            public ZonedDateTime deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(parser.readValueAs(String.class));
    }
}
I am getting below error : Could not read document: Text '2017-10-01T01:00+0000' could not be parsed at index 16 (through reference chain:

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because you're using wrong date format.

`2017-10-01T01:00` is not suitable for `ZonedDateTime` because it does not have offset section.

The correct representation must have offset, for instance: `2017-10-01T01:00+02:00`, the next code will work fine:

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2017-10-01T01:00+02:00")
```

At the same time `2017-10-01T01:00` could be represented by `LocalDateTime`, the next statement will complete without errors:

```
LocalDateTime.parse("2017-10-01T01:00")
```

**Note:** you don't have to write your own deserializers, everlasting is already implemented, just use `jackson-datatype-jsr310`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have a doubt here.If I send date as "yyyy-mm-dd" from postman,How can I convert this to Zoneddatetime format in java code.

Comment: What time zone you expect it to have?

Comment: Can I set to some default time zone?

Comment: Of course you can, you can for instance add missing time and offset in java code. But I believe it is bad idea.  There is no point of using `ZonedDateTime` if you don't operate with time zones. Try to use proper java types for representing this dates, eg. "yyyy-mm-dd" could be represented via `LocalDate`.

Comment: ok.What if I get the date in below format : 2017-11-05 18:30:00+0000 and I want to convert this to 2017-11-05 18:30:00+00:00.
I did something like this : 
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+XX:XX");
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.parse(s, formatter);

Now I am getting " Text '2017-11-05 18:30:00+0000' could not be parsed at index 20 ".